# Неправильно срабатывает ajax-представление

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть файл welcome с кодом, в нем есть меню в котором при помощи ajax-представления можно переходить на разные страницы. Так же к файлу подключен хедер, в котором такое же меню, но ajax-представление работает неправильно, переходит на другие страницы... Нажимаешь на page1 открывается страница page2...page2 на page3, page3 на page4, page4 так и остается page4, а если сразу на page4  то открывает page1... подскажите что я не учел?

Файл header.php:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <nobr> menu </nobr>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page1"><a href="#top"> page 1</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page2"><a href="#top"> page 2</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page3"><a href="#top"> page 3</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page4"><a href="#top"> page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</div>
```

Файл welcome.php:

```
@include('header')
<ul class="nav navbar-nav centermenu">
  <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page1"><a name="top"> page 1 </a></li>
  <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page2"><a>            page 2 </a></li>
  <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page3"><a>            page 3 </a></li>
  <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page4"><a>            page 4</a></li>                       
</ul>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var tpls = ['page1.blade.php', 'page2.blade.php',  'page3.blade.php', 'page4.blade.php'];

    $('.loadBtn').click(function(){

        $('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
        $(this).addClass('activeEv');

        loadContent($(this).index());
    });
    loadContent(0);

    function loadContent(index) {
        if (!tpls[index]) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: tpls[index],
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

  });
</script>
```

Добавил пару строк в скрипт, получилось:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tpls = ['languages-eng.blade.php', 'targets-eng.blade.php',  'bd-eng.blade.php', 'instruction-eng.blade.php', 'cooperation-eng.blade.php'];

    $('.loadBtn').click(function(){

        console.log($(this).attr("value") + ", index=" + $(this).index());

        $('.loadBtn').removeClass('activeEv');
        $(this).addClass('activeEv');

        loadContent($(this).index());
    });
    loadContent(0);

    function loadContent(index) {
        console.log(index + ": " + tpls[index])
        if (!tpls[index]) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: tpls[index],
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

апач выдает ошибку:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
```

В браузере пустой экран

Comment: а на когда нажимаете на page2, что происходит? а на page3?

Comment: Igor, я в вопросе дописал: Нажимаешь на page1 открывается страница page2...page2 на page3, page3 на page4, page4 так и остается page4

Comment: хм, давайте разбираться. Добавьте `console.log($(this).attr("value") + ", index=" + $(this).index())` в обработчик клик, и `console.log(index 
 + ": " + tpls[index])` в начало `loadContent`

Comment: а меня почему то смущает вот эта строчка `loadContent($(this).index());`. Почему не использовать value у элементов ? А то ведь даже не угадать что при нажатии на кнопки происходит с индексом (который кстати начинается с нуля). А еще он может выдавать забавные результаты если DOM меняется

Comment: alexoander,  а как именно использовать value? Вы правы в том, что this может передавать абсолютно разный контент!!!Я тоже думал об этом, но т.к. я не очень силен в jquery не особо пойму как подключить value

Comment: @Александр `this` в обработчике - совершенно определенный DOM-элемент

Comment: Igor, сделал как Вы сказали,ничего не поменялось...я не пойму тогда почему this сместился?

Comment: @Александр Вы вставили `console.log` в код? Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос, что выводится в консоль при клике на каждый элемент.

Comment: @Igor, добавил в описание вопроса код и вывод логов апача, как Вы говорили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле header.php:

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <nobr> menu </nobr>
  </a> <!-- clouse here -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page1"><a href="#top"> page 1</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page2"><a href="#top"> page 2</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page3"><a href="#top"> page 3</a></li>
      <li  class="loadBtn"  value="page4"><a href="#top"> page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  <!-- </a> - this clouse-tag delete-->
</div>
```

Закрыть тег /a нужно перед списком меню, а НЕ после него, как было у меня! Получается что когда ПОСЛЕ списка скрипт ajax срабатывал дважды и поэтому переходило на следующую страницу!